# Проблема с конфигурацией и работой Event listener Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Возникла проблема, которую не могу побороть уже второй день...
Не сохраняется в базу сущность. Вылетает эксепшен. Вот, собственно он. Подозрение на эвент лисенер, точнее конфигурацию. Т.к на Spring Boot этот код отрабатывал идеально. Собственно вот код:

```
19-Mar-2019 17:35:15.159 SEVERE [http-nio-49012-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/blog] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;] with root cause
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory$PropertyAccessorClassGenerator.generateCustomAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.createAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.potentiallyCreateAndRegisterPersistentPropertyAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.getPropertyAccessor(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:455)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.lambda$null$1(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$mapOnContext$4(PersistentEntities.java:115)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.mapOnContext(PersistentEntities.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.lambda$getBeanWrapperFor$3(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:81)
    at java.util.Optional.flatMap(Optional.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.getBeanWrapperFor(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.touch(AuditingHandler.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markCreated(AuditingHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForCreate(AuditingEntityListener.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.preCreate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:767)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:304)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:489)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source)
    at services.service.impl.EmailVerificationTokenService.createVerificationToken(EmailVerificationTokenService.java:47)
    at services.event.listener.OnUserRegistrationCompleteListener.sendEmailVerification(OnUserRegistrationCompleteListener.java:43)
    at services.event.listener.OnUserRegistrationCompleteListener.onApplicationEvent(OnUserRegistrationCompleteListener.java:34)
    at services.event.listener.OnUserRegistrationCompleteListener.onApplicationEvent(OnUserRegistrationCompleteListener.java:17)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:399)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
    at web.controllers.AuthConroller.registerUser(AuthConroller.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at services.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Конфигурация модуля транзакций:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "services")
@Import(value = {DaoConfiguration.class})
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private OnRegenerateEmailVerificationListener onRegenerateEmailVerificationListener;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(587);

        mailSender.setUsername("");
        mailSender.setPassword("");

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMailMessage templateSimpleMessage() {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setText(
                "This is the test email template for your email:\n%s\n");
        return message;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean getFreeMarkerConfiguration() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean bean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();
        bean.setTemplateLoaderPath("/templates/");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Код контроллера:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class AuthConroller {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthServices authService;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody RegistrationRequest registrationRequest,
                                          WebRequest request) {
        Optional<User> registeredUserOpt = authService.registerUser(registrationRequest);
        registeredUserOpt.orElseThrow(() -> new UserRegistrationException(registrationRequest.getEmail(),
                "Missing user object in database"));
        UriComponentsBuilder urlBuilder = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/" +
                "/registrationConfirmation");

        OnUserRegistrationCompleteEvent onUserRegistrationCompleteEvent =
                new OnUserRegistrationCompleteEvent(registeredUserOpt.get(), urlBuilder);
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(onUserRegistrationCompleteEvent);

        registeredUserOpt.ifPresent(user -> log.info("Registered User returned [API[: " + user));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse("User registered successfully. Check your email" +
                " for verification", true));
    }

    @GetMapping("/registrationConfirmation")
    public ResponseEntity<?> confirmRegistration(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        Optional<User> verifiedUserOpt = authService.confirmEmailRegistration(token);
        verifiedUserOpt.orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidTokenRequestException("Email Verification Token", token,
                "Failed to confirm. Please generate a new email verification request"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse("User verified successfully", true));
    }

    @GetMapping("/resendRegistrationToken")
    public ResponseEntity<?> resendRegistrationToken(@RequestParam("token") String existingToken) {
        Optional<EmailVerificationToken> newEmailTokenOpt = authService.recreateRegistrationToken(existingToken);
        newEmailTokenOpt.orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidTokenRequestException("Email Verification Token", existingToken,
                "User is already registered. No need to re-generate token"));

        User registeredUser = newEmailTokenOpt.map(EmailVerificationToken::getUser)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidTokenRequestException("Email Verification Token", existingToken,
                        "No user associated with this request. Re-verification denied"));

        UriComponentsBuilder urlBuilder = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/api/auth" + "/registrationConfirmation");
        OnRegenerateEmailVerificationEvent regenerateEmailVerificationEvent = new OnRegenerateEmailVerificationEvent(
                registeredUser, urlBuilder, newEmailTokenOpt.get());
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(regenerateEmailVerificationEvent);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse("Email verification resent successfully", true));
    }
}
```

Метод создания токена и сохранения в базу:

```
public void createVerificationToken(User user, String token) {
    EmailVerificationToken emailVerificationToken = new EmailVerificationToken();
    emailVerificationToken.setToken(token);
    emailVerificationToken.setTokenStatus(TokenStatus.STATUS_PENDING);
    emailVerificationToken.setUser(user);
    emailVerificationToken.setExpiryDate(Instant.now().plusMillis(emailVerificationTokenExpiryDuration));
    log.info("Generated Email verification token [" + emailVerificationToken + "]");
    emailVerificationTokenRepository.save(emailVerificationToken);
}
```

Ивент лисинер:

```
    @Component
@Slf4j
public class OnUserRegistrationCompleteListener implements ApplicationListener<OnUserRegistrationCompleteEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private EmailVerificationTokenService emailVerificationTokenService;

    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;

    @Override
    @Async
    public void onApplicationEvent(OnUserRegistrationCompleteEvent onUserRegistrationCompleteEvent) {
        sendEmailVerification(onUserRegistrationCompleteEvent);
    }

    private void sendEmailVerification(OnUserRegistrationCompleteEvent event) {
        User user = event.getUser();
        String token = emailVerificationTokenService.generateNewToken();
        emailVerificationTokenService.createVerificationToken(user, token);

        String recipientAddress = user.getEmail();
        String emailConfirmationUrl = event.getRedirectUrl().queryParam("token", token).toUriString();

        try {
            mailService.sendEmailVerification(emailConfirmationUrl, recipientAddress);
        } catch (IOException | TemplateException | MessagingException e) {
            log.error(String.valueOf(e));
            throw new MailSendException(recipientAddress, "Email Verification");
        }
    }
}
```

Какова идея, пользователь регистрируется и отправляет данные с формы. Он сохраняется в таблицу и одновременно создается токен, который тоже сущность и должен сохраниться в базу. Этот токен сохраняется в базу и отправляется на почту пользователю. Пользователь сохраняется в базу, а токе на моменте сохранения выкидывает этот экшепшен. Хелп:)

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Проблема была с версиями в подключаемых зависимостях. В частности, старая версия  aspectj и cglib.version, которые были несовместимы с текущей версией спринга

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт. Проблема была с версиями в подключаемых зависимостях. В частности, старая версия aspectj и cglib, которые были несовместимы с текущей версией спринга.